# PHP, MySQL database.`table`, quotes present, I don't understand

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an app that uses the mysql tables defined in an array. This is so they can be changed quickly for use in the dev/live environments.

Other than issues regarding why the dev environment uses completely different table structure, I've got what I'm hoping is a simple question.

I've got one table defined differently than the others, like so:

```
'customer' => Array(
  'variables' => 'customer.`variables`'
)
```

While all the other tables are defined this way:

```
'customer' => Array(
  'orders' => 'customer.orders'
)
```

The difference being the pair of ` surrounding the table name. Obviously this isn't a valid table (and I can't find a table named simply 'variables' in the database. Quick ideas how I can track this one down? I'm assuming at this point that it has a special meaning to the MySQL server, however that's just a guess.

Note: There are many other tables defined in the same array, I've simply excluded them. Every other definition is like the second example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> An identifier may be quoted or
>   unquoted. If an identifier contains
>   special characters or is a reserved
>   word, you must quote it whenever you
>   refer to it. The set of alphanumeric
>   characters from the current character
>   set, “_”, and “$” are not special.
>   Reserved words are listed at Section
>   8.3, “Reserved Words”. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in
>   a qualified name must be an
>   identifier, so it need not be quoted.)
>
> The identifier quote character is the
>   backtick (“`”):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

**Update:** In this context, it doesn't seem that `variables` actually *needs* escaping. However, automated tools (including MySQL itself) tend to escape it; probably, because the escaping algorithm is not context-sensitive and it merely finds words in a list:

```
mysql> set sql_quote_show_create=off;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> show create table my_test;
[...]
CREATE TABLE my_test (
  id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `variables` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Is `variables` a reserved word?  I'm familiar with `SHOW VARIABLES`, but I looked at a list of reserved words and didn't see `variables`.  Is it documented?

Comment: AJ's question, however, is still a good one. It would appear, at least on the surface, that the reason it has the backticks is because it's the word 'variables', which is a special SQL word (it's not on the list of reserved words) and at the same time doesn't need the backticks because its an identifier in this case. Sounds as if it's not needed, at least in this scenario, maybe that changes from dev to live.

Comment: @Jeff - Certainly, the question is good. I've updated my answer.